# c# virtual dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class with a dictionary object.  Any class that derives from that class, I want to override the dictionary with it's own implementation.

How can this be achieved as the virtual keyword is not valid here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have virtual fields, but you *can* have virtual properties.

Additionally, it would be a good idea to declare the property-type to be of the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface rather than the  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` concrete- type, since this class is not designed for inheritance.

E.g:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _myDictionary 
                  = new Dictionary<string, int>();

protected virtual IDictionary<string, int> MyDictionary 
{
   get
   {
      return _myDictionary; 
   }
}
```

Subclasses will not see the field; only the property will be visible. They are free to override the property and provide their own implementation; for example by returning an instance of a custom-type that implements the interface.

Comment: Thanks.  That works perfectly.  Can I also ask, I have set this up in the base class main form.  If I need access to that dictionary from a different class within the same assembly, is it better to make the field static, or create an object of the main class and use it that way?  Thanks again.

Comment: I think you're looking for one of the access modifiers `public`, `protected internal` or `internal`, depending on your needs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
public class Base
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public virtual IDictionary<string, string> DictInstance
    {
        get { return this.dictionary; }
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    private MySpecialDictionary otherDictionary = new MySpecialDictionary();

    public override IDictionary<string, string> DictInstance
    {
        get { return this.otherDictionary; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make dictionary variable private and serve it via virtual getter. Derived class cannot completely throw inherited member away, only override class functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the field as IDictionary, then each subclass initializes it with a different implementation. Or do as Ani suggest.